# Ampere's law and magnetic circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, magnetic-fields

For magnetic circuit there is an equation NI=HL. This equation is obtained by applying Ampere's law. H is magnetic field intensity and L is the length of the circuit. In following picture the equation reduced to I=HL as there is only one turn:

[image]

However, if take a shorter path and apply the Ampere's law, HL must be smaller than before due to shorter path but there is still same current I enclosed (see below). Why?

[image]

btw, sorry for the ugly picture.

Comment: The intensity of the field is greater on a smaller path like that, because your loop is closer to the current.

Comment: @Raskolnikov What if small path is not closer? (actually my drawing bad). At the left side it can take the same distance as original path. At the right side the path is out of the iron core so B is zero. Then we still get a smaller integral.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, In my picture only a small section of the iron core is wrapped with electric wire (one single turn). The enclosed current is the same for both the large and the small loops in the pictures.